# Range condition using UINT32_MAX

Tags: c++, c

I need to check if a int64_t is in the range -UINT32_MAX <= x <= UINT32_max

I've tried like so:

```
if(x >= -(UINT32_MAX) && x <= UINT32_MAX)
```

But it seems that -(UINT32_MAX) overflows to 1

Any ideas?

Comment: What type is `x`?

Comment: Use `-(int64_t)UINT32_MAX`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `-(UINT32_MAX)`, the negation is performed in the type `uint32_t` (and the parentheses have no effect). Negating within the `uint32_t` type wraps modulo 2<sup>32</sup>, so it produces 1. To truly negate `UINT32_MAX`, do it in a wider type, as in `- (int64_t) UINT32_MAX`.

In `x >= - (int64_t) UINT32_MAX && x <= UINT32_MAX`, the *usual arithmetic conversions* will be performed. Given that `x` is of type `int64_t`, these will not be a problem. However, for some other types, this expression may fail. For example, if the type of `x` were `uint64_t`, then, in `x >= - (int64_t) UINT32_MAX`, the right operand would be converted to `uint64_t`, producing a large positive value, and the comparison would not produce the desired result.

Answer (score -1):

`stdint.h` defines `UINT32_MAX` as follows:

`#define UINT32_MAX (4294967295U)`

Notice the `U` at the end. That restricts `UINT32_MAX` to be an unsigned integer. Adding a minus in front of it will set it to 1.

Hence, not a good idea to use `UINT32_MAX` to check limits on `int64_t`.

Comment: I edited the question the variable to check is a int64_t so the range is fine my bad

Comment: Updated the answer.